# Collection fixtures in Meteor 1.3

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I am using Meteor 1.3 and am unable to get my fixtures to appear on the client.

For testing purposes, I created a new Meteor project and followed the [tutorial steps up to this point](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections).

1. I created a file fixtures.js in /imports/api/
2. I import this in /server/main.js
3. When I start the server, I see the console log line indicating that the file was imported and if I query the collection using the mongo shell, I see the fixtures.
4. If I query the collection from the client, I see nothing.

Am I missing something to get the flixtures to appear on the client? I have not modifed the installed packages, so autopublish is still present.

Comment: Is there any error in the console? Did you import the collection in the template where you are using the it? Is data present in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

If you just use chrome console to query your collection, this will not work anymore in 1.3. If you want so, then you should put it into global namespace:

```
global.CollectionName = CollectionName
```